# Is it possible to give focus to drawable added in editText for Accessibility in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, accessibility

I want have EditText and clear button(to the right of the EditText)to clear the text in the EditText and also want to implement accessibility on both of the  elements.I can do in following ways :

- By adding clear button as drawable right in the EditText.
- By adding clear button as the separate button to the right of EditText in the layout.

I am keeping 2nd way as the optional if its not achievable by first way.I want know to if it is possible to have EditText and drawable right (clear button)to it and make both EditText and drawable accessible (ie when accessibility is on i want to first focus on EditText and then when in swipe or navigate focus should go to drawable clear button).

Thanks.

Comment: use EditText and ImageView  in a linearlayout

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i want to know if it is achievable by adding image as drawable Right in EditText and make drawable focusable.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @Bhavanahegde did you solve this issue? I'm also stuck with this issue and I've used drawableRight.